# gsutil does not work when called from exec() from PHP on a compute engine

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, gsutil

We are trying to run gsutil command on a Google compute engine from PHP, and we are getting no results.

When running gsutil via SSH, it is working fine, but when from PHP `exec()`, nothing happens.

No errors are returnes from `exec()`.

Any ideas?

Comment: our php is running under nginx user, but gsutil seems to work only for root, any way to change that ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that you're not seeing any output because `exec()` is not capturing stderr.

I'd also guess that you're running into a similar issue as mentioned in https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/419. If you don't set the `BOTO_CONFIG` environment variable, gsutil searches for a boto config file (which contains your credentials) in the home directory of the user that invoked it. The `nginx` user typically doesn't have a home directory, so you'll have to store your boto file somewhere else and set `BOTO_CONFIG` with the path to that file. If you configured gsutil as `root`, that boto file will be somewhere under root's home directory (either `~/.boto` or `~/.config/gcloud/legacy_credentials/...` if installed as part of the Cloud SDK).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, we will try that right now.

Meanwhile we tried same thing on app engine flexible environment, it still didn't work, and there we don't have access to users and configs., I'll get back with news when we try on compute engine first.

Comment: We had to export PATH and HOME, after that gsutil started to work on compute engine! Now trying the same on app engine, still no luck.

Comment: When we SSH to an instance of an app engine, there is gsutil, but when we run it from code, it says "permission denied", as we set the right path for it.